# Hazelcast spring boot app not working as ec2 service

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, hazelcast

I created spring boot app with code in [this guide](https://hazelcast.com/blog/spring-boot/). hazelcast.yaml is as follows.

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      aws:
        enabled: true
        host-header: ec2
    interfaces:
      enabled: true
      interfaces:
        - 10.9.*.*
  map:
    books:
      time-to-live-seconds: 60
```

but I get errors

> 2021-07-15 10:14:08.101  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.i.config.AbstractConfigLocator       : Loading 'hazelcast.yaml' from the classpath.
> 2021-07-15 10:14:08.911  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [4.2.1] Interfaces is enabled, trying to pick one address matching to one of: [10.9.*.*]
> 2021-07-15 10:14:09.098  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.9.0.4]:5701 [dev] [4.2.1] Hazelcast 4.2.1 (20210630 - 06a4018) starting at [10.9.0.4]:5701
> 2021-07-15 10:14:11.700  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy   : Using AWS discovery plugin with configuration: AwsConfig{accessKey='***', secretKey='***', iamRole='null', region='null', hostHeader='ec2', securityGroupName='null', tagKey='null', tagValue='null', hzPort=5701-5708, cluster='null', family='null', serviceName='null', connectionTimeoutSeconds=10, connectionRetries=3, readTimeoutSeconds=10}
> 2021-07-15 10:14:11.717 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [10.9.0.4]:5701 [dev] [4.2.1] Node creation failed
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to configure discovery strategies
> at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:161) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:58) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.newDiscoveryService(DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.java:29) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.createDiscoveryService(Node.java:343) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.(Node.java:269) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.createNode(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:148) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:117) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:211) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:190) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:128) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:91) [hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastServerConfiguration$HazelcastServerConfigFileConfiguration.hazelcastInstance(HazelcastServerConfiguration.java:55) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
> at com.example.hazelcast.HazelcastApplication.main(HazelcastApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[app.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at java.util.regex.Matcher.(Matcher.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at com.hazelcast.aws.RegionValidator.validateRegion(RegionValidator.java:33) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsClientConfigurator.createAwsClient(AwsClientConfigurator.java:53) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy.(AwsDiscoveryStrategy.java:79) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategyFactory.newDiscoveryStrategy(AwsDiscoveryStrategyFactory.java:50) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.buildDiscoveryStrategy(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:195) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:141) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
> ... 45 common frames omitted
> 2021-07-15 10:14:11.718  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [10.9.0.4]:5701 [dev] [4.2.1] Shutting down connection manager...
> 2021-07-15 10:14:11.792  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [10.9.0.4]:5701 [dev] [4.2.1] Shutting down node engine...
> 2021-07-15 10:14:11.804  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.hazelcast.instance.impl.NodeExtension  : [10.9.0.4]:5701 [dev] [4.2.1] Destroying node NodeExtension.

But when I tried fargate service with just removing `host-header: ec2`, it worked. How can I run as ec2 service?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is for ECS on EC2.

If you are using EC2 instance then configure as below

```
<hazelcast>
    <network>
         <join>
             <multicast enabled="false"/>
             <aws enabled="true">
                 <tag-key>my-ec2-instance-tag-key</tag-key>
                 <tag-value>my-ec2-instance-tag-value</tag-value>
             </aws>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

Refer to below link
https://guides.hazelcast.org/ecs-embedded/

Comment: Not working with the same errors. only difference in log is change of IP

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for some reason the region is not resolved from your EC2 Instance. Maybe you have the Metadata API disabled. I suggest to configure the region manually.

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      aws:
        enabled: true
        region: <your-region>
        host-header: ec2
...
```

Comment: After that change I'm getting this error. `com.hazelcast.aws.RestClientException: Failure in executing REST call`. Do you have idea about that.

Comment: Then, I suggest you check why your EC2 does have access to AWS EC2 Metadata Endpoint.